# Implement PeerToPeer Calls using ms graph API

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, calling-convention, microsoft-graph-teams

I am able to create a call through my react application using graph API to a MS-Teams user in organization which is working fine call is being made to the graph API and it's dialing to the user in the organization but I don't think user can interact without any device setup i.e laptop speakers and all in order to listen and speak over the call.
API USED :

To make a call
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/calls

To get call summary
[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/%7Bid%7D)

I want to know how :

1. Do I need to create interface in my ReactJs App just in order to provide user all the facilities of calling? Right now I have only provided the Call button.
2. How can I handle the callback in the development phase and test things in my react app as callback are only sent to the https routes.

Note : I am using NestJs as backend.

Can anyone please provide a demo for this how to handle things properly as its now like a brain twister working with MS Graph APIs. I shall be highly obliged for the same as I am trying this thing first time.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To Create call You will need to register the calling bot. Which enables your bot to create a new outgoing peer-to-peer or group call, or join an existing meeting. Please go throgh this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot#:%7E:text=Select%20the%20Calling%20tab%20on,%2Fteamsapp%2Fapi%2Fcalling%20.) and [samples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples) for more info.

Comment: I have zero knowledge of .Net framework and every sample is in that only. Please provide something in the JavaScript. Also I am able to make a call but I am unable to neither test things nor able to understand how to handle callbacks as it strictly requires HTTPS callback route.

Comment: @Sanjeev_gupta2812 - Currently we don't have samples in Javascript. Could you please check if this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/call-notifications#authenticate-the-callback) may help you.

Comment: Okay No problem. Thanks